# Get the name of the clicked item

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I'm using a class extending BaseAdapter to fill a gridView on my layout.
When I click  on one of the elements of the gridView I want to get the name of the item I clicked on (where name is name in R.drawable.name)

So here's what I wrote

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChoseActivity.this,
                            GameActivity.class);
                    String ab = getResources().getResourceEntryName(arg1.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("AB", ab);
                    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

I have this error

```
02-27 13:46:49.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 13:46:49.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24862): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
02-27 13:46:49.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceEntryName(Resources.java:1499)
02-27 13:46:49.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at com.example.kersplatt.ChoseActivity$1.onItemClick(ChoseActivity.java:36)
02-27 13:46:49.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-27 13:46:49.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
```

I don't understand because the image clicked IS in my ressources

**EDIT1**

I tried this in getView of my Adapter but still have the same error:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.currentimage);
```

Comment: The id of the view isn't related to the drawable resource it holds. You can set id to views and then access them by using for example: findViewById(id) in your activity. In your case, if you want to retrieve the drawable that was added to the view then you first need to cast the View to the type of view you have used, like ImageView and only then retrieve the id of the drawable and get the name of the resource.

Comment: The id here points to the tag of the view you are trying to find.

Comment: and what should I do to find the name of the drawable?

Comment: is the element a imageview???

Comment: @lokoko: even if I do imageView.setTag(R.drawable.currentimage) in my adapter, I still have the same error

Comment: Cant you just use arg1 which would have the view ?

Comment: No because I then load animation which drawables are different according to the image in gridview clicked and the name of these drawables contain the name of the imageview clicked, you see?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getDrawableId` function so you'll need to do something like set a tag for the ImageView when you change its drawable.

In your adapter class `getview()` set tag to the imageview object, let the tag be the id of the resource of the drawable.

```
imageview.settag(r.drawable.currentimage)
```

now when you want the drawable onClick of gridview, get the tag and get drawable from its `id`

```
int drawableId = (Integer)imageview.getTag();
```

and you can get the name of the drawable using

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int drawableId);
```

Comment: what's r.drawable.currentimage in getView? How can we obtain the image clicked?

Comment: id of the drawable, and also u need to set onclicklistener to all the elements u want to find source on. simply extend class with onclicklistener and assign setonclicklistener to "this"

Comment: in the code u have tried rather than creatin new object use (imageview)view.findviewbyID(idofimageview), this will return the existing iview element

Answer (score 0):

First thing for u if your image in the **resources/drawable** folder than simply make an arraylist  of type like `arraylist<integer>` and next thing add all those image to the arraylist after that use that arraylist in your adapter class(supposing that u know how to inflate a custom layout and use your arraylist to display those all image in the gridview so for the text as you ask in your question make an arraylist for text also and here the type will be `arraylist<Integer>` only because it will hold the text value which are in resource/drawable folder(as u say in question) or u can make your own arraylist of type `arraylist<String>` and add some String(name) to it as u like.

Next thing all the arraylist will have some position or u can set the Id for the image`(using method imageview.setId())` while inflating the layout and check or retrieve the id or position in your adapter class on the clicklistener of that imageview so after u find the position just take value of position and search the element or item in the arraylist of text (which is already created before) and get the item from the arraylist specific position when user click event occur and after that display or print as u like.if code is required regarding the question pls let me know and sorry for my english language.

Answer (score 0):

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(arg1.getId());
```

You are not specifying the context here. Could be:

```
this.getResources().getResourceEntryName(arg1.getId());
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

I spent somtime looking for a way to dot it. The easiest way to do it in your case is to use arg3 which contains the id of your clicked view something like this

```
String ab = getResources().getResourceEntryName(int()arg3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get the name of the Image if you have the resource id of the Image. You can use getResourceEntryName(resourceId)

if you are using ArrayList for image path then use

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(ArrayListName.get(arg2));
```

if you are using array then

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(Arrayname[arg2]);
```